# Imported modules have no tips in Pycharm while the code can run successfully

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm on Windows10 to import some packages.

```
Pycharm version: 2019.3.1
Python version：3.8.1 32bit
```

I have used virtual environment.

All the packages were installed by pip. And when I import it, these are some red underline. That mean there may be some errors. While the code can run without any question.

Besides, when I use the methods in those package, there is no tips for those methods.

[image: project interpreter]
[image: errors]

Comment: How do you run your code, from PyCharm or from command line?

Comment: @XuhangYes Have you open the project with the exact project root or additional folders?

Comment: Add your errored lib to interpreter (+ sign)

Comment: from Pycharm.
With the exact project.
yeah, I have added all the lib and I can see them in the interpreter, just like the first picture

Comment: Try Ctrl+Click on `charts` in `from pyecharts.charts`, where it brings you?